# word for "said as if offended"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that means "said as if offended"?  As in:

> "Who owns the beater Dodge parked by the back door?"
>   "Beater?" a bearded man said in a wounded tone.

Is there a more concise way to say "said in a wounded tone"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Huff](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/huff):

> To react indignantly; take offense.
>
> "Beater?" a bearded man huffed.

Not the best, but it's used this way.

Comment: I think **huff** is Ok. The definition of Longman Dictionary says:  To say something in a way that shows you are angry, often because you have been offended. 
*"You should have warned me," she huffed.*

Comment: "Bristle" also fits.